# Reading Properties file vs HashMap Java

Tags: java

In my application I have defined around 1,00,000 values in properties file. Currently I am copying all data in map and accessing it. Is it a good way or we can directly read values from properties file?

Comment: any framework you using?

Comment: I have no idea what **1lakh** means but you can read directly from a properties file if you want to.

Comment: @JohnJoe we are using spring framework

Comment: you can also categorize values and keep different maps, and do lazy loading.

Comment: Do you have a memory / performance constraints?

Comment: @DhavalSolanki Please review my answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot difference between the HashMap and propertyFile processing.
Let me clear you by example :-

suppose you have 1 million key value pair entries to process.
Behavior of HashMap :-

1. `HashMap` :- If you are searching for a particular key in the `HashMap` and you have implemented correct `hashcode()` and `equals()` contract then by the hashing the getting and setting key, value will be fast as it will use hashing and red black tree indexing for searching.

   cons :- you have to initialize the `HashMap` i.e. reading every value from File and put it to the `HashMap`.
2. PropertyFile :- If you look at the internal implementation of `PropertyFile.java` it internally uses the HashTable.

   `public class Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object>`
   So once you loaded the property file into the object. The performance comparison between them is same as `HashTable` vs. `HashMap` performance.

Comment: but what if i create a varible of properties and load once the server is started and then read data from properties object instead of reading  the file. so in my scenario the file will be read only once then which is faster properties object or hashmap ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can direct read properties file from Java.
Examples

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

By the way, If you read about 1,00,000 values that will increase the IO of your application. Suggest you use HashMap instead of fetching values from properties files each time.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing a file on the hard drive takes a lot of time (worst if that is a network hard drive). Loading a large file into a map structure uses a certain amount of memory. Once your files is loaded in your map, accessing data should be really faster than read them from a file each time. If you dispose enough memory, it is better to use map.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy depends on the requirements and constraints you have. Based on the two dimensions (requirement: speed, constraint: memory) this can be a list of possible solutions:

1. speed and no constraints: read the whole properties in a map
2. no requirements and limited memory: read from the file
3. speed and limited memory: use a cache to read an amount of properties which is a trade-off between speed and memory used. The trade-off depends on an empirical evaluation considering:

   - how the properties are used by the application?
   - which eviction policy is better to use? (answer to this question is wired to the previous one)

Speed and memory belong to the system area. There could be other requirements or constraints that belong to the application area, for example: properties are read only or they can be written by someone so you need to reload them when necessary; once the applications started and is configured with this properties it has no more access to the source of the properties.

So there are many good solutions but no one that fits all the situations. If you are in doubt start with the simple solution and then when a requirement is clear or a constraint appear move to another that fits.